# skip specflow specs under certain conditions

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

I am looking at setting up SpecFlow for various levels of tests, and as part of that I want to be able to filter which tests run.

For example, say I want to do a full GUI test run, where I build up the dependencies for GUI testing on a dev environment and run all the specs tagged @gui, with the steps executed through the gui. Also from the same script I want to run only the tests tagged @smoke, and set up any dependencies needed for a deployed environment, with the steps executed through the api.

I'm aware that you can filter tags when running through the specflow runner, but I need to also change the way each test works in the context of the test run. Also I want this change of behaviour to be switched with a single config/command line arg when run on a build server.

So my solution so far is to have build configuration for each kind of test run, and config transforms so I can inject behaviour into specflow when the test run starts up. But I am not sure of the right way to filter by tag as well.

I could do somethig like this:

```
[BeforeFeature] 
public void CheckCanRun()
{
   if(TestCannotBeRunInThisContext())
   {
       ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
   }
}
```

I think this would work (it would not run the feature) but the test would still come up on my test results, which would be messy if I'm filtering out most of the tests with my tag. If there a way I can do this which removes the feature from running entirely?

Comment: how are you running the tests when you want to not run these tests? Using the built in VS runner? From the command line? On the build server?

Comment: @SamHolder both during development using the resharper test runner and on the CI server (with different configuration run on different levels of build), and also if possible a few specs on a deployed server to check that deployment has gone OK...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no I don't think there is anyway to do what you want other than what you have outlined above.

How would you exclude the tests from being run if they were just normal unit tests?

In ReSharper's runner you would probably create a test session with only the tests you wanted to run in. On the CI server you would only run tests in a specific dll or in particular categories.

Specflow is a unit test generation tool. It generates unit tests in the flavour specified in the config. The runner still has to decide which of those tests to run, so the same principles of choosing the tests to run above applies to specflow tests.

Placing them into categories and running only those categories is the simplest way, but having a more fine grained programmatic control of that is not really applicable. What you are asking to do is basically like saying 'run this test, but let me decide in the test if I want it to run' which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Thanks. What you've said there actually does give me an idea of a different way to achieve this. I may be able to make a generator plugin to suppress tests I don't want at the generation stage, assuming I have access to the right information at that point.